# P2P Audio Sharing in Android

Tags: java, android

I am working on an Android project where I can share audio files to another phone with the same app. The audio file should be playing at the other end. I am using Firebase Storage to upload and play the file.

However, I would like to establish a p2p communication (I still can stick with Firebase but I would like to try this out to share files). I have tried to look up for some tutorials on it but no luck!

Comment: P2P on the cellular network is going to be veeeery hard.

Comment: If you find it please let me know..I too am working on a similar app.thanks

Answer (score 0):

Simple advice:

1. Upload File to Firebase Storage
2. Write url of uploaded file to Firebase Realtime Database
3. Listen to Firebase Realtime Database with other device
4. Get file url and download file to device
5. Play audio file

Comment: Thanks I'll thry that